# how to push array into another array in angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```
this.addToCart = function(id,name,category,price) {

        alert(id+"name"+name);
        var eachProduct = [
                {
                    "name": name,
                    "id": id,
                    "category":category,
                    "price":price
                }
            ];

        //$scope.obj = item;
        //alert($scope.obj.name);
        alert("product Name :"+eachProduct[0].name);

        var arrayList = [];
        arraylist.push(eachProduct);

        sessionStorage.setItem("addedProductsList", eachProduct);

        return "success";
```

and I am retrieving the values arrayList from  the sessionStorage

```
var retrieveArray= sessionStorage.addedProductsList;
alert(retrieveArray.eachProduct[0].name);//getting undefined
```

I am retrieving in another service
how to push each product into arrayList and store it in the session storage.

Comment: Try replacing: `alert(retrieveArray.eachProduct[0].name);` with `alert(retrieveArray[0].name);`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Local- and SessionStorage is intented to be used with primitive data types. You need to convert your array to a string before saving it:

```
sessionStorage.setItem('addedProductsList', JSON.stringify(eachProduct));
```

and parse it back to an array when retrieving it:

```
var retrieveArray= JSON.parse(sessionStorage.addedProductsList);
```

Comment: Local and session storage store string values, and that is the only data type they store.

Comment: Demo using AngularJS `toJson`/`fromJson` methods: http://plnkr.co/edit/DIkSfMAoSwfhOOGkE1qh?p=preview

Comment: @JLRishe Yep, you're right. My point was that storing a number still works better than storing arrays or objects, even though you get a `String` and not a `Number` back.